# Posting a Post with Images in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to create a social media post, so it must have a title, a general description, and a 1 or more images attached to the post, so I created a Post entity, and a PostFile entity with a reference to the Post it belongs to. Now, the PostFile doesn't contain the file because it's supposed to be on the file system of the server. it just contains a UUID that represents its name on the file system.

this is the endpoint

```java
@PostMapping("/{userId}/posts")
    public ResponseEntity<PostDTO> createPost(
                @PathVariable Long userId, 
                @RequestPart("post") Post post, 
                @RequestPart("images") List<MultipartFile> files
        ) {
                PostDTO createdPostDTO = userService.createPost(userId, post, files);
                return ResponseEntity.ok(createdPostDTO);
    }
```

but I don't understand how to use it
this is what I'm trying to do in Hoppscotch, but it trows a 500 error
[picture of hoppscotch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8foV.png)

I tried with a RequestBody before, but you cannot attach images inside a json file